# Firebase notifications on Android phone with screen lock

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, screen-lock

We develop an android app to show Firebase notification to user. The implementation is working very well in emulator everything is works fine, no problem.

- When install the app to my phone:

  - When the phone is unlocked, app is foreground: Message arrived, works fine
  - When the phone is unlocked, app is background: Message arrived, works fine
  - When the phone is unlocked, app is destroyed: Message arrived, works fine
  - When the phone is locked, I hear the sound of message arrived, but I can't unlock the phone! I press the power button, and nothing happening. The phone is not responding since 5-10 seconds! After that time, the screen is on but I can't do anything on it. I can't turn off the phone, can't restart. The only way to unlock is start camera by pressing twice the power button, after a few seconds the camera is showing than I can swipe out the notification. After that everything is going well with the phone.

My code is similar which is on firebase site: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: You mean your phone lags when you  receive notification from firebase console?

Comment: not exactly, during 5-10 secs it hangs. I can't do anything on it.

Comment: What phone are you using? This never happened to me. Are you using in-app messaging?

Comment: Samsung A50. Android 9.

Comment: Are you using Firebase in-app messaging?

Comment: No I using cloud messaging

Comment: Can you try removing all the code you have added to get a notification first? Then add the libraries  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'`

Comment: Then their is no issue if you are using cloud messaging. Just do what I've said in previous comment and run app and then start a campaign from cloud messaging

Comment: Have you tried on any other phone?

Comment: You said remove all code? Include the service implementation? I haven't tried it other phone...

Comment: Remove the service implementation from your Manifest as well. Just add the libraries I said and send a new notification from the cloud messaging console. [Follow This method](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-925075/)

Comment: I removed the service implementation... it's not hanged...

Comment: Is the Issue solved ?

Comment: It looks like, thank you... But there was nothing in the implementation, just that code from the firebase...

Comment: Good to know :-) I have posted it as an answer, you can accept it so that others know the issue is solved :-) and upvote if you like it ;p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212092/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-hosszuful).

Comment: the firebase-core lib wasn't added... That was the problem... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send normal notifications to the app using Firebase Cloud Messaging, code is not required.

Just add the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0' 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
```

And create a new notification like this.

[image]

It looks like Your messaging service may be misbehaving.. or check if you have latest dependencies installed.